# perl: long delays during repeated system calls

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin, delay

not sure if this is a perl problem, or a cywin problem, or a Windows problem:

I'm running perl inside cygwin under Windows8. We have a comprensive number of small scripts for individual tasks, and I've recently written a top level script, which repeatedly calls several of these scripts via 'system' calls. All scripts for themselves run flawlessly, however execution is only happening in chunks, i.e. the top level script starts to operate, and after about 10 seconds it stops and the computer is idle for another 10-15 seconds, then starts again for 10 seconds, and so on. Apart from this script the PC is only running the usual Windows background processes, i.e. the top level script is the only process causing significant CPU load.

The script is too long to show here, but essentially consists of stuctures where a few variables are defined in loops and then combined via sprintf strings to call the scripts , just like the following snippet:

```
(...)
foreach $period (@periods)
{
    foreach $wt (@wtlist)
    {   
        foreach $type ('WT', 'Ref')
        {
            $out=1;
            $dir1=0*$sectorwidth;
            $dir2=1*$sectorwidth;
            $addfile0 = sprintf("%s/files/monthly_recal/%s%s_from%s.%s_%03d.da1", $workingdir_correl, $nameRoot, $wt, $type, $period, $dir1 ) ;
            $addfile1 = sprintf("%s/files/monthly_recal/%s%s_from%s.%s_%03d.da1", $workingdir_correl, $nameRoot, $wt, $type, $period, $dir2 ) ;
            if (-e $addfile0 && -e $addfile1)
            {
                $cmd = sprintf ( "perl ../00Bin/add_sort_ts.pl $addfile0 $addfile1 %s/files/monthly_recal/tmp/%s%s_from%s.%s.out%02d 0 $timeStep\n", $workingdir_correl, $nameRoot, $wt, $type, $period,  $out ) ;
                print ($cmd);
                system ( $cmd ) ;
            }
        }
    }
}
(...)
```

All variables are defined (simple strings or integers) and the individual calls are all working.

When this top level script is running, it's running several loop iterations after another, so I don't think it's a matter of startup delays of the called scripts. To me it looks more as if Windows denies too many system calls in a row. I have other perl scripts withut 'system' calls, which run for 10 minutes without showing this intermittent behaviour.

I have no real clue where to look for, so any suggestion would be appreciated. The whole execution time of the top level script can take several hours, therefore any improvement here would greatly improve efficieny!

--UPDATE: From the discussion to Hakon's answer below it turned out that the problem lies in the shell that is used to run the perl scripts - intermittent operation appears when the code is run from Windows `cmd` or a non-login shell, but not when run explicitly from a login shell (e.g. when using `bash --login` or staring `mintty -`). I will open another thread soon to clarify why this happens... Thanks to all contributors here!

Comment: Please show the script.

Comment: Do you have anything like "AppSense" running on the machine that intercepts any process creation?

Comment: Not that I know of, TaskManager did not show anything called 'AppSense'. AFAIK, the system is pretty much standard Windows.

Comment: *"We have a comprensive number of small scripts"* : The code just shows a single script. How does this script `add_sort_ts.pl` look like?

Comment: It reads two input files ($addfile0, $addfile1) consisting of measurement time series (i.e. each line starts with a time stamp followed by a set of data), and brings all time stamps in a sequential order. The sorted time series is written to an outfile in directory %s/files/monthly_recal/tmp/. The parameters '0' and $timestep are used during the sorting process. -- I could have shown other code snippets calling other scripts doing different operations on time series data, which show the same problematic behaviour, so I think it's a problem of the top level script, not of the called scripts.

Comment: @vobTry to narrow down the problem by reducing the number of scripts. How many scripts do you need to call in order to observe the problem?

Comment: @HåkonHægland: There are typically quite a number of input files to read even at this loop (severeal hundred), and the file size of each input file can vary from 2MB down to a few kB. The problem occurs regardless of the called script and the involved input file sizes; the working periods are always quite similar (10 seconds of operation, 10-15 seconds idling). This regularity to me looks more like a problem of Windows/cygwin scheduling mechanism. (See also my edit above on CPU load.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to simplify you problem a little bit? It will help to locate the problem more easily. For example, the following code running on Windows 10, Strawberry Perl 5.30 (running from CMD not Cygwin) shows no problems:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
for my $i (1..10) {
    system 'cmd.exe /c worker.bat';
}
```

with a simple `worker.bat` like:

```
@echo off
echo %time%
timeout 5 > NUL
echo %time%
```

The output from running the Perl script is:

```
10:35:00.71
10:35:05.18
10:35:05.22
10:35:10.17
10:35:10.22
10:35:15.15
10:35:15.19
10:35:20.19
10:35:20.23
10:35:25.15
10:35:25.20
10:35:30.16
10:35:30.21
10:35:35.14
10:35:35.18
10:35:40.16
10:35:40.20
10:35:45.16
10:35:45.21
10:35:50.15
```

Showing no delays between the `system` calls.

Comment: This setup works fine even when we increase to 2500 iterations. However, the problem reappears when the script calls another perl script rather than the batch file (e.g. via `system ("perl ./worker.pl");`), and `worker.pl` only contains a simple print command (e.g. `print "1 ";`). Then, operation stops after about 1150 iterations (about 25 seconds on my machine), pauses for another 25 seconds, and then performs the next ca. 1150 iterations.

Comment: @vob Ok, interesting. It might be a buffer problem let me check

Comment: Are you printing to the cygwin terminal window? (the simple print command). It works fine (no delays) here in the CMD terminal window

Comment: No, I'm calling this from a cmd window, and output also goes there. I have the cygwin /bin/ directory in my Windows %PATH%.

Comment: Hakon, did you check with >2000 iterations of the loop? With only 10 iterations I don't experience problems as well. If this works for your setup (running perl directly from Windows), then I guess the problem lies somewhere at the interface between cygwin and Windows...

Comment: yes I checked with 2000 iteration, but maybe we should also try output to file instead of terminal? there may be differences in behavior

Comment: I tested writing to file and it seems to also work fine here.

Comment: For me, writing to file produces the same intermittent operation...

Comment: On Win32 perls you can use `system(1,command)` to run command in a detached process. I don't know if this applies to cygwin. Otherwise you can use `system('start', command)`. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Good idea! On cygwin, the native shell is `bash`, so I tried `system (bash -c 'perl ./worker.pl')`. This actually leads to non-intermittent operation. -- However, it looks as if the overhead from invoking bash slows execution of each single iteration down. The overall runtime for 2500 iterations with bash is 2:12 minutes on my PC, while the intermittent version takes 2:20min. That's 6% better, but I was hoping for something in the order of 50% by removing the idle periods while maintaining the execution speed during the operational periods...

Comment: Turns out that the problem lies not in the code but in the teminal emulator. Actually, I was running all of the code above from a Windows 'cmd' window; this works because the cygwin directories are in my %PATH%. However, when I run the same code from the "Cygwin terminal" (actually a mintty), there is no more intermittency, and the system calls without the bash detour take about half the time, as expected. -- Many thanks to all who shared their thoughts and suggestions, much appreciated!

Comment: Small correction: it's **not** the terminal emulator, but the fact that the shell running inside is a **login shell**. Starting mintty from the Windows desktop icon opens bash as a login shell, and the script runs non-intermittently. Opening mintty without starting a login shell gives the old intermittent operation.

Comment: how big is the amount of text you are producing in CMD ?